# What's the correct way to bind this interface?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm having a hard time to come up with the correct way to translate the last part (<GPUImageInput>) into the binding. Any suggestions?

```
@interface GPUImageFilter : GPUImageOutput <GPUImageInput>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here : http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries#Binding_Protocols and http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/api_design#Models.

Depending on what's in `GPUImageInput`, I'd bind it with the `[Model]` attribute, then make `GPUImageFilter` inherit from it

```
[Model]
//Look, no BaseTypeAttribute
interface GPUImageInput {
    //[Export] everything you need
}

[BaseType (typeof (XXXX))]
interface GPUImageFilter : GPUImageInput {
    //[Export again]
}
```

Hope it helps